# Generated Service error "DataServiceAdminExceptionException" in WSO2 Data Service Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have Generated Service in WSO2 DSS, if I select one table then Generated Service sucessfully. But if I select multiple table then Generated Service unsucessfully as error bellow:
"DataServiceAdminExceptionException"
Please help me fix this problem 
Thanks so much !